# Mutating columns with reduce2 and rlang

Tags: r, purrr, rlang

I am trying the following:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)

df <- data.frame(a = 1:2)

reduce2(list(df, df, df), letters[2:3], ~ mutate(.x, !!(.y) := 2:3))
#> Error in local_error_context(dots = dots, .index = i, mask = mask): promise already under evaluation: recursive default argument reference or earlier problems?
```

I do know many ways of mutating columns to a dataframe, but I am trying to learn `rlang`.

The expected output:

```r
  a b c
1 1 2 2
2 2 3 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `reduce2` is the correct function here, since you aren't actually using any items an the list of data frames after the first iteration. The function that is passed to `reduce2` takes three arguments - the first is the object being reduced, the second is the next item in `.x` and the third being the next item in `.y`.

That means you can still use `reduce2` if you want, by doing:

```r
reduce2(.x = list(df, df, df), .y = letters[2:3], 
        .f = function(A, B, C) mutate(A, {{C}} := 2:3))
#>   a b c
#> 1 1 2 2
#> 2 2 3 3
```

But note that you are not using the second argument in the function body. You could do it just with `reduce`:

```r
reduce(list(df, 'b', 'c'), ~ mutate(.x, !!.y := 2:3))
```

Answer (score 3):

A method to combine `purrr::reduce()` and `rlang` is:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

reduce(letters[2:3], ~ .x %>% mutate(!!.y := 2:3), .init = df)

#   a b c
# 1 1 2 2
# 2 2 3 3
```

where the trick is to assign `df` to the argument `.init`.

Answer (score 2):

I am sure you are aware that you can do `df[letters[2:3]] <- 2:3` to achieve the same output but I don't think this is what you are looking for.

To use `purrr` and `rlang` you may use -

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

bind_cols(df, map_dfc(letters[2:3], ~df %>% transmute(!!.x := 2:3)))

#  a b c
#1 1 2 2
#2 2 3 3
```

And another way would be -

```
map(letters[2:3], ~df %>% mutate(!!.x := 2:3)) %>% reduce(inner_join, by = 'a')
```

Comment: Thanks, Ronak, for your answer! The goal of my question was to try to understand why my approach did not work. So, I was trying to get a solution the closest possible to my approach, to help me to identify my error.